# Weird error when trying to make a http multipart-form data request in swiftui

Tags: swift, urlsession

Here is the code for uploading a file using a POST request and form-data body type.

```swift
let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)"
urlRequest.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let fileName:String = String(request.fileURLForFormData!.path().split(separator: "/").last ?? "")
let fileData = try Data(contentsOf: request.fileURLForFormData!)
var uploadData = Data()

// Append file data
uploadData.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
uploadData.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"\(fileName)\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
uploadData.append("Content-Type: \(fileName.mimeType())\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
uploadData.append(fileData)
uploadData.append("\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

// Close the form data
uploadData.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

// Set the request body
urlRequest.httpBody = uploadData
let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.upload(for: urlRequest, from: Data(contentsOf: request.fileURLForFormData!))

return .success((data, response))
```

Here is the error i am getting using `data`, `dataTask`, `upload` and `uploadTask`.

The request of a upload task should not contain a body or a body stream, use `upload(for:fromFile:)`, `upload(for:from:)`, or supply the body stream through the `urlSession(_:needNewBodyStreamForTask:)` delegate method.

Comment: The error message clearly tells you what you should do - what's so "weird" about that error? Have you actually tried doing what the error message is telling you to do?

Comment: Sorry, but yeah i did that and got the same error again. Updated the code above.

Comment: The error tells you exactly what is happening

Comment: I am new to swift, can you add a sample code to upload a file using multiform body and POST request, that'd very helpful

Answer (score 0):

When you create an upload request, the parameter you pass as `data:` gets sent as the request body.  To the body data you'd actually be sending right now is the raw file data, not the form-encoded data.

And the API also complains because you shouldn't be setting the body on the request at all.

To fix this:

- Pass the uploadData object as the `from:` parameter when creating the request instead of passing the contents of the file on disk.
- Delete the line that sets `urlRequest.httpBody`.